# Python: name 'RandomOverSampler' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, imblearn

Am trying to use imblearn to do some over and under sampling on a dataframe. However when calling either function (e.g. `RandomOverSampler`), it says that it is not defined.

the imblearn library is included

`import imblearn`

when calling print(imblearn.**version**) , it also prints the version number 0.8.0

```
import imblearn
OverSampling = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
```

any help appreciated as am not able to understand the possible reason (probably something very simple)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your import problem is already solved in many other places on line and here on Stack Overflow -- the first of which is the misspelled name.

Comment: @Prune done :  ) . I actually searched and most solutions just suggested re-installing the package which also did not help

Comment: Please refer to any tutorial on importing a package.  Your posted code does not try to call anything in `imblearn`.  As given, `RandomOverSampler` is a function elsewhere in your name space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import should look like this `from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler` since you're trying to import and directly instantiate a specific class from the `imblearn` module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to have resolved the function undefined issue.  however when calling the fit_sample method, it says that there is not attribute by this name: OverSampling = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
X_Over = Data.drop(["Gender"], axis=1)
Y_Over = Data["Gender"]

X_Over, Y_Over = OverSampling.fit_sample(X_Over, Y_Over)

Comment: I'm think for that version you actually want `fit_resample()` instead of `fit_sample()`